# Нахождение минимального набора вырожденных последовательностей ДНК

Tags: алгоритм, строки, биоинформатика

Как всегда, небольшое упрощенное вступление:

В биологии в большинстве случаев для описания последовательности ДНК достаточно 4х литер - A,G,T и C (это обозначения нуклеотидов: аденин, гуанин, тимин и цитозин). Для специфических целей удобно также пользоваться литерами, обозначающими вырождение, например:

```
R = A или G, т.е. на данной позиции присутствует либо A, либо G, других вариантов нет
Y = T или C
W = A или T
V = A или C или G
N = A или C или G или T
```

существуют обозначения для всех вариантов вырождений ([вот ссылка на текстовый файл со всеми вариантами](https://github.com/vicontfreetime/primers/blob/master/list.txt))

Соответственно, к примеру, когда мы говорим о последовательности **RAGCTY**, это значит, что мы имеем в виду варианты **AAGCTT** или **AAGCTC** или **GAGCTT** или **GAGCTC**. Это прямая задача - нахождение всех вариантов вырожденной строки. Она проста.

Но есть обратная задача. Очень часто для исследований/диагностики требуется набор коротких ДНК-последовательностей (праймеров) (обычно, от 8 до 30 нуклеотидов). Заказ каждой последовательности стоит времени/денег, поэтому я могу, к примеру, рассчитывать, что мою заявку на 50 вариантов удовлетворят, а вот больше - уже откажут. При этом, если я вижу, что две или более последовательности составляют вырожденность (как в вышеуказанном примере), я стараюсь подать в заявке именно вырожденный вариант. Синтез по времени и деньгам занимает практически столько же, зато я имею 2 или более последовательностей на "одноразовый заказ" для своего исследования.

Это просто, когда последовательностей мало и они короткие. Но порой (часто такое бывает при исследовании нового вируса или сильно измененного штамма уже известного) **имеем**:

Набор большого количества последовательностей (строк) одной длины, состоящих из литер A, G, C, T.
**Задача**: найти минимальное множество вырожденных последовательностей, описывающее именно этот набор.

Т.е., допустим, на входе  **AAGCTT** + **AAGCTC** + **GAGCTT**. Решение: **RAGCTT** + **AAGCTC**
***Неправильные решения:*** (**NAGCTT** + **AAGCTC**) или **NAGCTN** , поскольку в первом случае мы имеем 5 последовательностей, а во втором - 16, тогда как у нас их всего 3, и в дальнейшей работе (как теоретической, так и практической мы будем иметь неправильные последовательности).

В качестве примера хорошей (возможно, идеальной) работы: [набор реальных невырожденных праймеров](https://github.com/vicontfreetime/primers/blob/master/in.txt) (отсортированы, в количестве 94 штук) и [результат после поиска вырождений](https://github.com/vicontfreetime/primers/blob/master/out.txt) (14 вырожденных праймеров)

Это просто, когда последовательностей хотя бы несколько десятков. Но когда речь идёт о сотнях тысяч (дальше будет отбор по другим критериям, которые, опять-таки, лучше работают с вырожденностями), то решение неочевидно.
Существующие пакеты предлагают решение для относительно небольших наборов. Алгоритм в них достаточно прост: первая строка попарно сравнивается со всеми остальными, при нахождении разницы в одну литеру обе строки удаляются из набора, заменяясь одной с вырождением по этой литере. Алгоритм неоптимален, и часто потом удаётся вручную слегка улучшить результат. Плюс, он не работает с большими наборами.

Можно ускорить этот алгоритм путём перевода строк в полубайтовые массивы: 
A = 0001, C = 0010, G = 0100, T = 1000. Тогда, к примеру, R = 0101, V = 0111, N= 1111 и т.п. Это должно весьма сильно ускорить сравнение при переборе, но, думаю, серьезного ускорения не добавит.

Есть идеи других алгоритмов решения обратной задачи?

Если кому интересен реальный материал - [2 миллиона 23-буквенных праймеров](https://github.com/vicontfreetime/primers/blob/master/primers23.zip) (в будущем проекте их больше -  более, чем в 2 раза, но и так файл весит 14 мегабайтов).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99105/discussion-on-question-by-viktor-tomilov----).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Допустим у нас есть набор:

```
AAA
AAT
ATA
CAA
GAA
```

Как видно, в наборе есть серия, в которой различаются только первые символы. Я подумал, что если мы можем отсортировать такой набор сортировкой подсчетом таким образом, чтобы элементы, которые различаются только одним символом на первой позиции оказались рядом, например

```
AAA
CAA
GAA
ATA
AAT
```

То, найдя такую серию, можно будет её смерджить в более короткую

```
VAA
ATA
AAT
```

И если проделать такую операцию сначала для всех серий для первого символа, потом для всех для второго и т.д., то в итоге получим что то сжатое. Корректность алгоритма я навряд ли докажу, но пока не смог найти контрпримеров.

Итак, идем к коду.

Для начала я добавил перечисление для типов

```
[Flags]
public enum Types
{
    None = 0,
    A = 1,
    C = 1 << 1,
    G = 1 << 2,
    T = 1 << 3,
    N = A | C | G | T,
    V = A | C | G,
    H = A | C | T,
    D = A | G | T,
    B = C | G | T,
    Y = T | C,
    M = A | C,
    K = G | T,
    S = G | C,
    W = A | T,
    R = A | G
}
```

Потом добавил методы для сопоставления типов и символов

```
internal static class Exts
{
```

В одну сторону

```
    public static char GetChar(this Types t)
    {
        switch (t)
        {
            case Types.A: return 'A';
            case Types.C: return 'C';
            case Types.G: return 'G';
            case Types.T: return 'T';
            case Types.N: return 'N';
            case Types.V: return 'V';
            case Types.H: return 'H';
            case Types.D: return 'D';
            case Types.B: return 'B';
            case Types.Y: return 'Y';
            case Types.M: return 'M';
            case Types.K: return 'K';
            case Types.S: return 'S';
            case Types.W: return 'W';
            case Types.R: return 'R';
            default: return '?';
        }
    }
```

В обратную сторону

```
    public static Types GetTypes(this char c)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
            case 'A': return Types.A;
            case 'C': return Types.C;
            case 'G': return Types.G;
            case 'T': return Types.T;
            case 'N': return Types.N;
            case 'V': return Types.V;
            case 'H': return Types.H;
            case 'D': return Types.D;
            case 'B': return Types.B;
            case 'Y': return Types.Y;
            case 'M': return Types.M;
            case 'K': return Types.K;
            case 'S': return Types.S;
            case 'W': return Types.W;
            case 'R': return Types.R;
            default: return Types.None;
        }
    }
}
```

После я добавил слегка модифицированную сортировку подсчетом

```
public class CountingSort
{
    public void Sort(string[] a, int w, int shift, int n, string[] aux)
    {
        int R = 21;

        for (int d = 0; d < w; d++)
        {
            var ind = (shift + d) % w;

            int[] count = new int[R + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                count[GetInd(a[i], ind) + 1]++;

            for (int r = 0; r < R; r++)
                count[r + 1] += count[r];

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                aux[count[GetInd(a[i], ind)]++] = a[i];

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                a[i] = aux[i];
        }
    }
```

Ну и получение значения по индексу я особо не продумывал, сделал как сделал. Знаю, что можно было переиспользовать код выше, но меня это сильно не заботило

```
    private static int GetInd(string s, int p)
    {
        if (s == null) return 20;
        var c = s[p];

        switch (c)
        {
            case 'A': return 1;
            case 'C': return 2;
            case 'G': return 3;
            case 'T': return 4;

            case 'N': return 15;
            case 'V': return 14;
            case 'H': return 13;
            case 'D': return 12;
            case 'B': return 11;
            case 'Y': return 10;
            case 'M': return 9;
            case 'K': return 8;
            case 'S': return 7;
            case 'W': return 6;
            case 'R': return 5;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

В итоге, добавил класс для декомпрессии

```
public class DnaCompressor
{
```

Основной метод, идея в том, чтобы пробежаться по всем позициям, для каждой позиции выполнить сортировку и после пробежать по сериям и смердждить, что можно.

```
    public void Compress(string[] lines, IProgress<int> progress)
    {
        var tmp = new string[lines.Length];
        int n = lines.Length;
        var maxpos = lines[0].Length;
        var sorter = new CountingSort();

        for (var pos = 0; pos < maxpos; pos++)
        {
            sorter.Sort(lines, lines[0].Length, pos, n, tmp);
            var ind = 0;

            while (ind < lines.Length && lines[ind] != null)
            {
                int start = ind;
                while (ind < (lines.Length - 1) && lines[ind + 1] != null && IsSame(lines[ind], lines[ind + 1], pos)) ind++;
                int end = ind;

                Types t = Types.None;
                for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
                    t |= lines[i][pos].GetTypes();

                var added = 0;
                foreach (var tt in new[]
                {
                    Types.N, Types.V, Types.H, Types.D, Types.B, Types.Y, Types.M, Types.K, Types.S, Types.W,
                    Types.R, Types.A, Types.C, Types.G, Types.T
                })
                {
                    if (t == Types.None) break;

                    if ((t & tt) == tt)
                    {
                        t &= ~tt;
                        var sb = new StringBuilder(lines[start]) { [pos] = tt.GetChar() };
                        lines[start] = sb.ToString();
                        added++;
                    }
                }

                ind++;
                for (var i = start + added; i <= end; i++)
                    lines[i] = null;
            }

            n = Scroll(lines, n);

            progress.Report((100 * pos) / maxpos);
        }

        progress.Report(100);
    }
```

Этот метод просто двигает пустые строки в конец массива

```
    internal static int Scroll(string[] lines, int n)
    {
        int startInd = 0; int endInd = n - 1;
        while (startInd < endInd)
        {
            while (startInd < endInd && lines[startInd] != null) startInd++;
            while (startInd < endInd && lines[endInd] == null) endInd--;
            if (startInd < endInd)
            {

                lines[startInd] = lines[endInd];
                lines[endInd] = null;
            }

        }
        n = endInd + 1;
        return n;
    }
```

Проверяем, все ли символы в строке одинаковые, за исключением указанной позиции

```
    internal static bool IsSame(string s1, string s2, int except)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < s1.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == except) continue;
            if (s1[i] != s2[i]) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Я в курсе, что код от идеала далек, тут много мест для оптимизаций, но я не хотел бы ничего оптимизировать, пока не пойму, корректный он или нет.

Чтобы можно было легко проверить алгоритм, я накатал небольшой интерфейс для него, где можно как источник или приемник строк выбрать текстбоксы или файлы.

[image: ...]

Все исходники доступны [тут](https://github.com/tym32167/DNAcompression)

Бинарник потыкать можно скачать [тут](https://github.com/tym32167/DNAcompression/releases/latest)

Comment: Проверил на том, что было уже посчитано Workshop'ом - результаты идентичны. Значит, подход работает

Comment: Мы готовим публикацию в PubMed. Поскольку ваш подход уже использовался в нашей работе, хотим выразить официальную благодарность в статье. Напишите мне, пожалуйста, на viktor(собака)tomilov.pw ваше английское имя в формате Имя Буква Отчества Фамилия и организация, где вы работаете (если хотите быть частным лицом, мы так и напишем :)) Либо просто свяжитесь, пожалуйста, со мной по данному e-mail

Comment: @ViktorTomilov отправил вам письмо ещё вчера утром, вы его получили?

Comment: Да, спасибо, необходимо было уточнить, как это будет выглядеть :) Отправил вам ответ.