# Хочу написать приложение для торговли на бирже(для трейдинга). Какие технологии лучше использовать?

Tags: api, любой-язык

Хочу написать для практики приложение для трейдинга. Пишу на C#, могу на C++. Какие технологии лучше использовать? Какие API? С чего начать и что почитать на эту тему? Может кто-то уже делал подобное поделитесь опытом. Буду благодарен.

Comment: Какое приложение? Клиентское? Серверное? Настольное/консольное? Вебсайт?  Для какого рынка? Что оно поддерживать должно? Вы бота писать собрались или какой то UI? Чем вас существующие клиенты не устроили? Чем существующие платформы для ботов не устроили?

Answer (score 3):

Мне очень приятно ответить на это вопрос... потому что я работал в компании, котрая занимается трейдингом, и сам писал ряд инструментов для игры на бирже.

По моему, прекрасно начать со SmartCOM'а. Это такая штука, котрая в приложение на Вашем компе транслирует события по конкретным инструментам. К тому же, у смарткома хорошие примеры, большой  форум с ответами на вопросы и довольно толковая поддержка.

А в процессе - Вы, скорее всего, сами поймёте, что Вам еще нужно. К сожалению, дальше дорожки классических торговых стратегий и HFT расходятся, потому что используют разные технологии, но эти различия станут заметны только после углубления в тему.

Считается также, что полезно знать классические протоколы FIX/FAST, но развитие современных api делает эти знания  уже не такими востребованными. Если только Вы сами не будете писать эти самые api :-)

С точки зрения используемого языка SmartCOM рассчитан на C#. Посмотрите еще StockSharp, пишется S#. Это расширение C# для работы с большим кол-вом нужных библиотек.

Но, как и в других областях разработки софта, в области "финансового программирования" есть разделение на клиентскую и серверную разработку. И если C# - это по большей части "клиентская сторона", то на серверах сейчас используется не только C++, но и Go и Rust.

С другой сторооны, давно уже есть терминалы, целиком работающие в браузере. Клиентская сторона - чистый js (ну, насколько js вообще бывает чистым)

Есть еще MetaTrаde, довольно востребованная на рынке штука, но она... в общем, как FORTRAN. Можно заработать на куусок хлеба, но удовольствия - никакого.

Успехов вам!

Comment: А язык то какой? Тип приложения какой посоветуете?

Comment: SmartCOM рассчитан на C#. Есть еще такая штука - StockSharp, S# - это вообще целый мир. Но там тоже всё основано с C#. А вообще это очень горячая область, и испоьзуются там на серверах не только C++, но и Go и Rust

Comment: Ну так напишите это в ответ. Видите же, что автор еще не определился со стеком технологий.

Comment: SmartCOM это компонент или программа или спецификация? Я так понял, для получения данных надо иметь конечную точку от брокера, которая поддерживает SmartCOM, верно?

Comment: https://iticapital.ru/software/smartcom/

Comment: вы правы в том смысле, что да - надо именть конечную точку того, кто будет транслировать Вам поток данных и осуществлять Ваши операции. Вряд ли, если Вы только начинаете програмимровать, вы подключитесь к бирже напрямую. Поэтому есть промежуточная организация, которая предоставляет Вам "услугу" - трансляцию данных и т.п. Разные брокеры предоставляют разные терминалы, клиенты и т.п. Я посовтовал то, с чего проще именно начать.

Comment: Я не автор вопроса, но я вот гляжу на ваш ответ и, со всем уважением к вашему опыту, вижу что информации вы даете мало. По сути только ключевые слова для гугла. Вы приаодите какие то названия, но не поясняете ни что это, ни как с ним работать, ни ссылку на доку или что то подобное. "это вам надо, это не надо, это классика, а это 'штука'" - это все не информативно. Вот я вам напишу: есть такая фигня AAA, но вам она не нужнв, но есть BBB - вообще классика, а вот CCC может вам пригодится - вы много из этого поймете?

Comment: для протокола: ответ полезный даже в нынешнем виде, я просто немного предлагаю его улучшить.

Comment: @tym32167, вы знаете, вы угадали мои мысли. Я вот вставал от клавиатуры, и подумал, что если написать развернутый ответ - то получится статья или тоненькая книжка. Но, мне кажется, что правильные ключевые слова - это для пытливого ума не намного хуже, чем тщательно составленный ответ "от азов". Потому что автор потратил на вопрос 5 строк, а  я написал уже в 10 раз больше, а если отвечу подробно - это будет еще больше в несколько раз. А потом, вопрос был - с чего начать? Как "начало" то, что я советую - это хорошая основа, которая сразу задаёт высокую планку.

Comment: Я бы не сравнивал кодичество строк с автором, ведь вы пишете ответ не только для него, но и для всего сообщества. И подобных тем я не припомню, потому даже мне было бы полено почитать. Но вцелом да, если давать более менее основательный ответ, то получится много текста. Я сам так делал [раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1012399/179763), [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/905310/179763), [три](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/889202/179763). Но если вы хотели донести только ключевые слова, куда копать, то ваше право.

Comment: @tym32167 -  вы правы, и Вы меня убедили. я постараюсь расширить ответ, включив в него отвты, в том числе, на "не заданные вопросы". Правда, мне понадится немного больше времени, возможно, пара дней

Comment: Я вас не принуждаю, пишите только если сами хотите это сделать. Пара дней это ничего, я помню, у меня [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1028461/179763) занял две недели и мне пришлось создавать репозиторий для него на гитхабе :)